# How to register a public key for an ethereum contract?

Tags: public-key

As part of the EOS token distribution there's an alert for the following risk:

If you hold EOS Tokens in an Ethereum account and fail to register a public key, then your EOS Tokens will not be part of the snapshot when the EOS Tokens become fixed and non-transferable on the Ethereum blockchain.

How can one register a public key?

Comment: You should read the [EOS.io FAQ](https://eos.io/faq.html). If you have more questions you can ask them directly in their social media accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate an EOS key pair and register it via the EOS Contribution smart contract "register" function.

You can register an EOS key pair here: https://nadejde.github.io/eos-token-sale/

If you'd rather generate it on your local machine, follow these steps: https://steemit.com/eos/@eosnewyork/securely-generating-an-eos-public-private-key-pair-using-official-eos-io-code

After you have the keys, go to the EOS Contribution smart contract on a site like myetherwallet.com and submit your public key for registration.

Post EOS launch, you'll be able to use the EOS private key to claim your native EOS tokens.

I'd recommend putting your keys in an MFA enabled password manager and/or writing them on paper and putting them in a safe place.

For more information please refer to Step 3 of this guide:  https://steemit.com/eos/@sandwich/contributing-to-eos-token-sale-with-myetherwallet-and-contract-inner-workings